# Undefined index when sending file to PHP via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hey there so am working on a file upload form and everything works but the PHP file

the HTML :

```
<h2>Upload a new video</h2>
<p>THEN SET UP THE BASIC INFORMATION</p>

<form class="upf" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1><i class="icono-upArrow"></i></h1>
    <input type="file" name="vid" id="video" />
</form>
```

the JQuery:

```
$.fn.upload = function(remote,data,successFn,progressFn) {
    // if we dont have post data, move it along
    if(typeof data != "object") {
        progressFn = successFn;
        successFn = data;
    }
    return this.each(function() {
        if($(this)[0].files[0]) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);

            // if we have post data too
            if(typeof data == "object") {
                for(var i in data) {
                    formData.append(i,data[i]);
                }
            }

            // do the ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: remote,
                type: 'POST',
                xhr: function() {
                    myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if(myXhr.upload && progressFn){
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(prog) {
                            var value = ~~((prog.loaded / prog.total) * 100);

                            // if we passed a progress function
                            if(progressFn && typeof progressFn == "function") {
                                progressFn(prog,value);

                            // if we passed a progress element
                            } else if (progressFn) {
                                $(progressFn).val(value);
                            }
                        }, false);
                    }
                    return myXhr;
                },
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                complete : function(res) {
                    var json;
                    try {
                        json = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                    } catch(e) {
                        json = res.responseText;
                    }
                    if(successFn) successFn(json);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};


$("#video").change(function(){
    $("#video").upload("includes/upload_vid.php", function(suess){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/upload_vid.php',
            success:function(data){
                $(".tesst").html(data);
            }
        });
    },$("#prog") );
});
```

now the JQuery works and i get the progress in my progress bar 
but the PHP don't do it part i think because am AJAXing the file the way i check the file info in the PHP is wrong any way here is the PHP code :

```
<?php
    $video_err ="";

    if($_FILES['vid']['type']=='video/mp4'){ 
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1023456789";

        $randName = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0 , 15);

        if(file_exists('data/users/videos/'.$randName.''.$_FILES['vid']['name'])){

        }// end of file exits
        else {
            $des = 'data/users/videos/'.$randName.''.$_FILES['vid']['name'];
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['vid']['tmp_name'], $des)){
                $video_err.= "Done";
            } else{
                $video_err .= "Sorry something went wrong, please try later";
            }
        }
    }// end of checking the file type[video]
    else{
        $video_err.= "Invaild File, sorry we now only accept .mp4 format";
    }
    echo $video_err;
```

The whole problem is that the `$_FILES['vid']` is undefined while i did ajax the file so what to do ?

Comment: Try a `var_dump($_FILES)` at the beginning

Comment: it returns an empty array ! i guess this should have returned the file info in an array ! but all it returned is array(0) {

Comment: I did try your code, and it's working for me. open your `php.ini` file and check if `file_uploads` is set to `ON`

Comment: everything is good with the PHP.ini and is the var_dump returning the info for you ?

Comment: Yes, it did, btw why are sending another request using `GET` method `function(suess){..`

Comment: No only that one that's  why am mindblowen i can't find something wrong  with code and yet it ain't  working

Comment: OK, so you could just use `$("#video").upload(
 "upload.php", 
 function(suess){
  $(".tesst").html(suess);
 },
 $("#prog")
);
`

Comment: will it worked now ! if you please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use :

```
$("#video").change(function(){
    $("#video").upload(
       "includes/upload_vid.php", 
       function(success){
           $(".tesst").html(success);
       },
       $("#prog") 
    );
});
```